# Error installing Grails plugin to local maven repository

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have created a Grails plugin using Grails 2.3.3 and trying to use the plugin in a Grails application which was also created using Grails 2.3.3.  Now, to use the plugin in the application, it needs to be published to a plugin repository first. So I attempted to publish the plugin into the local repository by using the commands:

```
grails clean
grails compile
grails maven-install
```

For the **grails maven-install** command I selected the option **2)InstallPlugin**. But then got an error:

```
Error installing plugin: No such property: ERROR_MESSAGE for class: Inst
allPlugin (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Ran the last command above with option --stacktrace and --verbose but did not get any clue as to what the problem might be. I also removed %HOME%/.grails directory and reran the above commands and still came with the same error.

After googling, I found  a JIRA for this issue which was closed stating that it happens when Grails version is changed and cleaning up cache files will get rid of this issue. However, that solution is not working for me and, by now, I have spent couple of hours trying to fix this. Also I did not change my Grails version.

Has anyone faced this issue with Grails 2.3.3 or with any recent version of Grails? What was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `install-plugin`, add a dependency in BuildConfig.groovy.

I don't know where the `2)InstallPlugin` "option" is coming from. The `maven-install` script packages your plugin and generates a POM file and the other files needed to be a valid published plugins. Then it copies these files to your local M2 directory, e.g. if your plugin name is "mycoolplugin" the files are copied to `$HOME/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/mycoolplugin`

Now you can "install" the plugin as if it had been published in a remote repo. Add a dependency in the app's `BuildConfig.groovy` using the usual format, e.g.

```
plugins {
    build ":tomcat:7.0.50"
    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.7"
    ...

    compile ":mycoolplugin:0.1"
}
```

Comment: Finally got this working after adding **build ":release:3.0.0"** and **compile ":rest-client-builder:2.0.1"** to the BuildConfig.groovy file for the plugin. The release plugin has a dependency on the  rest-client-builder plugin and therefore both must be included in the plugin project.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case - transitive dependencies should be resolved. Be sure to add `export = false` for both of those in BuildConfig.groovy so they don't leak into the containing app.